# mysql query - add number of equal records

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database and I wanted to know how I can make a sum of equal records.

My database has a field where it stores values ​​of type A B C and more.. How can I know how many times is the letter A B and C repeated?
I would like to have a result similar to this:

```
Letter  Total sum
A       4
B       12
C       192
D       50
```

Comment: Sample data as well as desired results are helpful.  Is there a reason this is not. a simple `group by`?

Comment: Luckily, the situation never arises.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, this is a `group by` query:

```
select letter, count(*)
from t
group by letter;
```